# Updatepanel and postback issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have 2 ddl, ddlCountry and ddlState, on selecting ddlCountry, the ddlState IS updated based on the chosen country BUT... when I select ddlState, the selected item in ddlState is not being marked as selected, thus I can't get the selected value.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:DropDownList 
    ID="ddlReceiverCountry" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="textBox" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlReceiverCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="true" >
</asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"  >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblReceiverState" runat="server" Text="State" CssClass="newReceiverlabel">
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList 
            ID="ddlReceiverState" 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="textBox" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlReceiverState_SelectedIndexChanged">     
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlReceiverState" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlReceiverCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"   />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Rephrase your question's title to avoid word "issue", please.

Comment: @Israel, You didn't set the autopostback="true" in ddlReceiverState dropdown.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan, You should probably post that as an answer instead of a comment, so that it can be accepted.

Comment: Kundan, I have tried this but it gives me a full page postback which I don't want.

Comment: @IsraelThieme `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlReceiverState" />` <-- what exactly do you *expect* this to do?

Comment: That is not supposed to be there. I did so many tests that probably I left behind the postbacktrigger. But still not working

Comment: Problem solved... just added a 2nd AsyncPostBackTrigger 

<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlReceiverState" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"  />

Thanks for all help... !!!!